# Adding references in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to add assembly reference for c# class file while converting from website to web application

I recently converted a VS project of mine from a website to a web application. When I did so, upon trying to view the site, I get the following error:

`The type or namespace name 'FunFactory' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

FunFactory is a class file in App_Code - what do I need to do to get this class recognized by my web application?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. Can you describe your situation in more detail?

Comment: Have you checked if the namespaces are the same for both the class file and the file referencing that class?

Comment: it's `App_Code` problem I believe (it was a while) - check this one out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038082/asp-net-web-site-cant-see-cs-file-in-app-code-folder - and specifically this one for conversion issues. http://stackoverflow.com/a/89719/417747

Comment: I posted an answer with details - let me know if that works (I think that's pretty close) - or close as answered etc.

Comment: app_code on the website or web app?

Answer (score 1):

it's App_Code problem I believe (based on what I know from your post)

Check this one out for some general discussion
[ASP.NET web site can't see .cs file in App_Code folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038082/asp-net-web-site-cant-see-cs-file-in-app-code-folder)

> and specifically this one for conversion issues.
>   [App_Code folder issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89570/app-code-folder-issues/89719#89719)

---

And this one describes the problem in some more details
http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html

> What should one do if there are isolated code files which need to be
>   added to WAPs?
>
> You can add code files under any folder call it “CodeFolder”,
>   “Controllers” or anything that makes sense in your project… Just avoid
>   putting them under “App_Code” unless you specifically want the server
>   side compilation behavior…

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, you can right click on the project and go down the context menu to "Add Reference". What you'll see after that does depend on your version of VS, but you'll likely get a set of tabs indicating what references you can add.

The other way to go about it is to do:

```
<Reference Include="[name]">
    <HintPath>[path]</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Or if it's a project...

```
<ProjectReference Include="[path]">
  <Project>[project-GUID]</Project>
  <Name>[name]>
</ProjectReference>
```

Good luck.

Edit: If you're trying to use a reference in AppCode, you'll need to do:

```
using [namespace];
```

...at the top of pages where you'd want to use it.

Comment: but which type of reference

Answer (score -1):

In Solution Explorer, right click on References, select "Add Reference"

Comment: but hich type of reference??