# The type X conflicts with imported type X

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations, partial-classes

In Entity Framework (Database first) I am trying to add some Data annotations to created classes.

In general: I have class X created:

```
namespace Info
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class X
    {
        public string SomeProperty {get; set;}
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to property `SomeProperty` to be ignored when serializing to JSON thus in `App_Code/Metadata` I create class X.cs and I add some MetaData:

```
namespace Info
{

    public class XMetaData
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string SomeProperty{get; set;}
    }

     [MetadataType(typeof(XMetaData))]
     public partial class X
     {

     }

}
```

Above I've manually changed namespace from `Info.App_Code.Metadata` to `Info` to have partial classes matched.

However in all places where I use X class i have warning

`The type Info.X in '.../Info/App_Code/Metadata/X.cs ' conflicts with the imported type Info.X in '.../Info/X.cs'. Using the type defined in '.../Info/App_Code/Metadata/X.cs '`

I expected that both partial classes would be merged however all occurrences are referring to that empty one X class.

Does anybody know what I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on what type of application you are developing, it could be wrong to put code in the App_Code folder, as it has certain effects on the contents. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89570/app-code-folder-issues).

Try moving the source files out of App_Code and make sure their "Build action" is "Compiled" in the properties window.

Answer (score 10):

Multiple partial class definitions that refer to the same class must all exist within a single assembly. In your example above during compilation the meta-data should be baked into the class and after compilation the class is whole, comprising of all the parts. Partial classes are a means to split the definition of the same class into multiple files.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) for an exhaustive explanation but note the following:

> All partial-type definitions meant to be parts of the same type must be defined in the same assembly and the same module (.exe or .dll file). Partial definitions cannot span multiple modules.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178466%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) link here explains that

> In general, ASP.NET creates an assembly for each application directory (such as App_Code) and one for the main directory.

For your case, although the partial classes are in the same project *and* the same namespace they are not being compiled into the same assembly.

Comment: But both classes are in one project, just in different Folders.

Answer (score 0):

remove the project bin folder, clean and rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Able to fix that in 2 methods.
1. Rename the App_Code folder
2. Move the .cs file into the root of the project.

Both methods works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved this by creating a sub-folder in APP_Code folder. Moved source code there. Added a namespace in depth. Clean and Build and everything is now OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if your .aspx page is the same name as the class(.cs) file.

Example: If the file is Guy.aspx and class file is Guy.cs, these will conflict.

Check the first line of the .aspx file and if it Inherits="Guy" then there is the conflict. Don't forget to change the Guy.aspx.cs file too if its already created, you will need to change the public partial class.